# negative epoch from Mongo are indexed as null in search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

If I create Date in cosmos db (from Mongo shell) and index it through Azure AI Search , the dates older than 01/01/1970 are displayed as null because Mongo dates are epoch based.

Is this limitation on Azure AI search side as its not able convert negative epoch value to date or its as per design?

How to index dates older than 01/01/1970 ? any recommendations ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a limitation but more of a design expectation. Azure AI Search might not interpret negative epoch values correctly, leading to the null result.

Now, for indexing dates older than 01/01/1970, here's a trick. You can add a fixed offset to your epoch dates to bring them into the positive range. For example, add the number of seconds between your date and 01/01/1970 to your epoch timestamp. This way, you're shifting everything into a positive epoch range that Azure AI Search grooves with.